# Is it possible to play an MP3 or WAV file from inside a JAR file using JavaFX.scene.media.Media?

Tags: java, jar, media, javafx-8

I'm fairly certain the answer is "no", but I want to release this application with default audio files contained in the jar. If possible I would like to be able to simply stream them as a resource into a Media file and play that media file, something like this:

```
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
.
.
.
Media m = new Media(this.getClass().resourceAsStream("File.mp3"));
//or
m = new Media(this.getClass().getResource("File.mp3"));
```

Is this possible? It keeps telling me "Bla bla URL can cannot be converted to String". 
If it's not possible I can live with it (I can just dump the audio files to a temporary directory and use them from there, and then delete them once the program is closed), but I would much prefer to just use them from within the jar.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html), the constructor for Media can only take a string, not a Stream. The string should be a URL, which may be a JAR URL.

You should be able to construct a JAR URL to the file in your JAR on the file system... documentation for a JAR URL is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html.